# Send data from activity to fragment on back button press

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am trying to pass data from an activity to a fragment, when i press the back button in the activity.

I have tried:

**In Activity**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
    finish();
}
```

**In Fragment**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    LOGD("Details", "Yes onActivityResult call");
}
```

But onActivityResultof fragment is not getting called.

Thanks.

Comment: The `onActivityResult` of the activity that contains the fragment will be called.

Comment: `LOGD` ? Is it typo?

Comment: Your fragment is in his activity context, more precisely "on top" of it. Please specify your scenario to clarify what you need

Comment: @firegloves the fragment is in another another activity context

Answer (score 0):

Create a setter for the variable in the fragment &
Keep a reference to the fragment in the parent activity, onBackPressed(), set the value -> yourFragment.setValue(xx)

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    HeadlinesFragment firstFragment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.news_articles);

        // Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
        firstFragment = new HeadlinesFragment();

       // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
       getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        firstFragment.setData("yourString");
        finish();
    }
}

public class HeadlinesFragment extends Fragment {

    String data;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
    }

    public void setData(String yourData){
            data = yourData;

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i am new to android and not sure how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :

Write this in your activity in which fragment is called

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
  //replace contentContainer with container defined in your activity
        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.contentContainer);
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```